# Log of multi-variable non-zero holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $f$ be a non-vanishing holomorphic function in $z_1,\dots, z_n.$ Suppose $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ is open and connected. Then $\log(f)$ is a holomorphic function.

$\textbf{Q:}$ I can see that $\log(f)$ is holomorphic by considering $\log\circ f(z_1,\dots, z_n)$ and applying chain rule on taking derivatives. Is there a way to define a multivariable version log function by considering $\int_{z_0}^z \frac{df}{f}$ as $f$ is non-vanishing where $z_0,z\in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $z_0$ is fixed?

It is not totally clear that given the above definition, the path integral is independent of path, though I can approximate it by rectifiable curves and then I have to shrink the curve. I think I need higher dimensional analogue of Goursat theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a loop $\gamma$ in $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ such that $f\circ \gamma$ has positive winding number with respect to $0$, then you don't really "I can see holomorphicity of $\log(f)$".

Comment: @user45765 You are confused,with the applicability of Cauchy-Riemann equations. In order to use them, you need the function to be differentiable. But if the conditions I mentioned above occur, then $\log(f)$ is not even continuous.

Comment: @user45765 Simple example. Let $dom(f)$ be an annulus centered at $z=0$, then $f(z)=z$ is non-zero on $dom(f)$. However, $\log(f)$ is not continuous on $dom(f)$.

Comment: @user45765 All I am saying is that you need to strengthen the conditions on your problem in order to really know that $log(f)$ is holomorphic. Once you do that it is simple to get integral representations that you want.

Comment: I think the book is referring to $U=C^n$ case. So I need to demand at least $U$ simply connected or elementary domain.